# How to connect two different bases of an irregular solid

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find a way to connect two different bases of an irregular solid, for example:

[image]

What I know is coordinates of each vertex of those two bases in 3D space. I need to find vertices of an opposite base with which each vertex has to be connected.

Comment: michtalt38, Dont you think number of vertices of two bases must be equal?

Comment: There are more than one solution. Are they on parallel planes? Are they allowed to intersect?

Comment: Are you still looking for an algorithm?